# unable to find valid certification path to requested target,idea

Tags: java

I am getting below exceptions.

> Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.8.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: I'm not so clear.